# Fetch API using JWT authorization

Tags: javascript, jwt, fetch-api, http-status-code-403, edx

My EdX API access request has been approved. As per the documentation, I have generated the client id and client secret on the admin website. Using  `fetch`, I have got the token from the https://api.edx.org/oauth2/v1/access_token URL by passing the client id and client secret. The token is a valid one I can see in my console. But when I pass this token as below, I get a 403 (Forbidden) error:

```js
fetch("https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs", {
  method:"GET",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "JWT " + token,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"
  }
})
.then( r => r.json() )
.then( res => console.log("SUCCESS " + res.count) )
.catch( err => console.log("ERROR  " + err) );
```

I have tried all the variations of the request like `credentials:true`, all the "Allow-control" headers etc, but this error persists. Upon using the dev tools on Chrome, the "Network" tab shows a completely different Fetch is used which is:

```js
fetch("https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs", {
  "credentials":"omit",
  "referrer":"http://localhost:3000/",
  "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body":null,
  "method":"GET",
  "mode":"cors"
});
```

The equivalent `curl` works at the command line and through Insomnia, and gets the data perfectly.

Comment: Try with curl sending an OPTIONS request to the same URL, without the Authorization request header added. That emulates the CORS preflight OPTIONS request your browser is making and that the browser sends before trying the GET request from your code, and which doesn’t include the Authorization request header. Also, remove your code that’s adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin request header. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header; it doesn’t work if you try to set it in request.

Comment: In looking at the docs at https://course-catalog-api-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_edx_apis.html there’s zero mention of how to use the API from frontend JavaScript code running a browser, and there’s no mention that the API is CORS-enabled. So it seems the API is intended to be used on;y from backend code — not from frontend JavaScript in a browser. So it’s likely you’re going to find that the answer to your question is that you need to abandon your effort to call the API from your frontend code and instead switch to calling it from your backend code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should I be using something like GraphQL Yoga and then get the data from the front-end code? Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Most systems seem to use not `JWT` but `Bearer`  as the prefix to the auth bearer token in the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the ins and outs of the specific system to which you are connecting, I cannot be authoritative, but most systems seem to use not `JWT` but `Bearer`  as the prefix to the authorization bearer token in the `Authorization` header:

```js
const res = await fetch("https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs", {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "JWT " + token
  }
});
const json = await res.json();
```